# Bottom of Mapbox annotation marker pin does not sit on coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm finding that any annotation image marker that is above some undefined size does not align the bottom of the marker to the coordinates. I've been unable to locate any documentation on it. Why is this and can it be fixed?

The coordinates are for the middle of Manhattan, New York City. Note how the green border sits well into the ocean. The coordinates are definitely right. When I use a different smaller image the annotation sits correctly and when I zoom in it sits correctly. But at anything above a 10.0 zoom level it does not sit correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate will align with the center of the custom image. Since there currently isn't a way to specify a custom offset, you will need an image with its bottom 50% empty so that its center aligns with the coordinate on the map when placed.